# turning dictionary of of dictionary into dataframe with one row, one column of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have a dictionary named test like so:

```
dct = {}
test = {'A': 1, '-A': 1, '-C': 1}
dct['key1'] = test
```

I want a df with one row with one column that looks like:

```
(A,1), (-A,1), (-C,1)
```

I've tried so many ways to iteritems() through the keys,value of dct creating list/tuple objects prior to invoking pd.DataFrame(x) but haven't been able to get the structure I want.

There must be an easy way to do this.

Comment: Can you add some input and expected output using a dictionary of dictionaries as your title suggests you have?

Comment: dct['key1'] = test = dictionary of dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to store the elements in some container if you want multiple  elements from the dict under a single column:

```
import  pandas as pd
dct = {}
test = {'A': 1, '-A': 1, '-C': 1}
test2 = {'A': 1, '-A': 1, '-C': 1}
dct['key1'] = test
dct["keys2"] = test2

print(pd.DataFrame([[d.items()] for d in dct.values()]))
```

Which will give you:

```
                          0
0  [(A, 1), (-A, 1), (-C, 1)]
1  [(A, 1), (-A, 1), (-C, 1)]
```

Comment: is it possible to have (A,1), (-A,1), (-C,1) instead of [(A, 1), (-A, 1), (-C, 1)]. I.e. not a list of the 3 pairs?

Comment: Nope,  you have to group the values somehow if you want to combine into a single column

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to get rid of the brackets, you first need to convert the list to a string and then strip off the head and tail brackets:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({'key1': [str([(k, v) for k, v in test.iteritems()])[1:-1]]})
                             key1
0  ('A', 1), ('-A', 1), ('-C', 1)
```

The data would obviously become vastly less useable after you do this.